# How to open interactive python console by default, under PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm IDE. When I stop at breakpoint - I can run interactive console in debug mode to see variables, evaluate simple expressions, etc.

However, this takes a lot of time every time when you need go there and click this small icon to start interactive session.

Is there any way to make this wonderful IDE start python console in interactive mode automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the debug console by default by setting:

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console > Always show debug console
[image: Screencap]

Comment: Any chance to make IDE jump to console automatically and immediately after breakpoint reached?

Answer (score 6):

To get the console to show by default which I believe is the desired outcome check the Focus on Breakpoints option on the right-click menu from the Console tab:

[image]